# Integration on a positive constant function on a set E of infinite measure

Tags: integration

Suppose E is of infinite measure and c is a positive constant function defined on E. Is "the integral of c over E" = c M(E).....?

I am convinced  that "the integral of c over E" is always $\le$ c M(E)...

... I understand that if $M(E) \lt \infty$ , then equality holds true. but it seems to me that in every article I read, no matter M(E) is finite or infinite the value the integral in question assumed to be equal to CM(E)...

So My question is what is the value in this integral when $M(E)= \infty$??

Answer (score 1):

If $c>0$, you can "define" $c \cdot \infty$ to be $\infty$, so that $c \cdot m(E)$ has the correct meaning regardless of whether $m(E)<\infty$ or $m(E)=\infty$.